# Fourier Transformation over 30000 .h5 files

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have 30k .h5 files and need to do a Fourier transformation over one specific data set in each file. Then I need to put them on a list.

Ultimately, I need a list of all Fourier transformations of each data file.

I know it is pretty expensive! But I would appreciate it if you could tell me whether there is any efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Hi, could you give more details and show what you tried so far? Maybe post the code for analysing a few files and then people can help you optimize it.

Comment: Sure, there are 30 000 .h5 files with dimensions of {512,1,1}. 512 Is one of the physical variables of my simulation, and 30000 is the time steps of my simulation. I need to do FT first on the first one, put them in a list with a dimension of {30000, 512, 1,1}, and again do FT over 30k time steps ( or Time).

Comment: Well, why don't you simply try to load all data into an array of size `{30000, 512, 1,1}` and then apply `Fourier`?

Comment: You can try to load the files with something like this: ``a = Developer`ToPackedArray[
 Table[Import["Filename_" <> IntegerString[i, 10, numdigits] <> ".h5"], {i, 1, 30000}]
 ]``. Of course, you have to adjust the file name and the number of digits you used for the file names.

Comment: Thanks. The file names have the following pattern. `scalarField_10.h5, scalarField_10.h5, scalarField_20.h5, ... , scalarField_29990.h5`. So I tried  `Table[IntegerString[10 i, 10, 6], {i, 1, 30000}]`, but the problem then will be the zeros behind the correct file name. For example, I want to read the _10.h5, but it starts with _000010.h5. Moreover, I have many datasets in each .h5 file. I need to add one specific data set.

Comment: @Lohrasb You need to add all relevant information (name patterns, which dataset in each file, etc) to your question. We can't help you without those details!